# Trying to determine if a stream is active php

Tags: php

I have the link to 2 audio streams

http://82.35.172.112:88/broadwave.m3u?src=1&rate=1
and
http://86.28.144.85:88/broadwave.m3u?src=1&rate=1

I need to find out which one is playing and then swap text etc. on the page

I've tried various different ways using fopen, fsockopen, curl to check, but nothing has worked

below is my latest try

```
$fp = fsockopen("82.35.172.112:88/broadwave.m3u?src=1&;rate=1", 88, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";;
}else{
echo "stream is there";

}
fclose($fp);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How would you manually determine which one is playing?  And when you say "nothing has worked", what do you mean? It always/never/inaccurately says they're working?

Comment: [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen) is for hosts, not for complete URLs. So visit the manual which has detailed examples for what you try to achieve.

Comment: cURL should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<?php

    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);

    if(!$fp = @fopen("http://86.28.144.85:88/broadwave.m3u?src=1&rate=1", "r")) {
        echo "no stream";
    } else {
        echo "streaming";
        fclose($fp);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but i still can't get this to work, all I get is "no stream" not sure why it worked for you and not me??